# XUbuntu 16.04 crashes when opening any browser

Tags: linux, vmware, xubuntu

I recently created a new VM as a test bed for a project, however when I opened the default browser, the system crashed (black screen, then an error dialog) with the following message:

```
VMware Player unrecoverable error: (svga)
Unexpected signal: 11.
A log file is available in "/home/user/vmware/VM/vmware.log".
```

If I read the log, I get the following:

```
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.001]| svga| E105: PANIC: Unexpected signal: 11.
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.001]| svga| W115: 
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.001]| svga| W115+ The core dump limit is set to ZERO; no core dump should be expected
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.275]| svga| W115: Core dumped.
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.275]| svga| I125: Core dump pipes to process /usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P, core file unreliable
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.275]| svga| W115: A core file is available in "/home/user/vmware/VM/core"
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.275]| svga| W115: Writing monitor corefile "/home/user/vmware/VM/vmmcores.gz"
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.277]| svga| W115: Dumping core for vcpu-0
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.277]| svga| I125: Beginning monitor coredump
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+0.814]| svga| I125: End monitor coredump
2017-07-17T13:23:38+01:00[+1.122]| svga| I125: Coredump en
```

After having no luck finding a solution, I decided to create a new VM. However...I get the same issue. So, I booted up an existing VM that has run seamlessly since it was created - and I get the same issue..

So....what could be causing this issue for all of my VMs?

Comment: perhaps your VM ran out of memory?

Comment: @meuh That's pretty unlikely - as mentioned, it effects all of my VMs, even if I create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Hard Drive issue with my PC!